# How does the variable work in the range() function?

Tags: python

I'm in the "for Loops and the range() Function" part of [Automate the Boring Stuff's chapter 2](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter2/), and while I understand how the function itself works, the variable is beyond me.

```py
for i in range(10):
    print("This will show up ten times")

# I got the above from a Python tutorial video

print('My name is')
for i in range(5):
    print('Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')')

# I got the above from Automate the Boring Stuff chapter 2
```

In the first example, this one is very simple, but I don't see the variable `i` get assigned anything, and it confuses me how that works. For the second example, I can see it's using an assigned variable, so that part makes sense to me. I do not understand `(' + str(i) + ')')`  too well, however. What's in it is generally daunting, and it'd be great if someone couple explains how this works. I understand its functionality, but if I were going off of memory, the first one seems much simpler to use.

Comment: It gets assigned, you just never use it.

Comment: `i` will go from 0 to 9, and each time the loop runs it will be increased by 1.

Comment: `print("This will show up ten times")` well, `i` is never used here. What *exactly* are you expecting to see, and why?

Comment: `'Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')'` just constructs a string using two constant `str` literals and whatever `str(i)` returns.

Comment: adding to @Sayse anwser. You can also replace "i" by "_" (underscore). The pythonic way saying "I don't need it, but something has to be there syntactically" -> `for _ in [...]: print()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can think of `range(10)` as a list of numbers from zero to 9 `[0, 1, 2, .., 9]`

when we loop through this list of numbers we assign the variable `i` to a number on this list.

ex:

loop1: `i=0`

loop2: `i=1`

loop3: `i=2`

loop4: `i=3`

and so on.

---

In the first example, you didn't use the variable `i` in anything so simply it didn't appear

---

In the 2nd one: we use `'Jimmy Five Times (' + str(i) + ')'`

which means adding the string `'Jimmy Five Times ('` to the variable `i` (after changing it from `integer` into `string`) then adding  `')'` at the end, and this process is called concatenating strings.

NOTE: You can't add `int` to `str` that's why we used `str(i)`

ex:

loop1: `i=0` -> 'Jimmy Five Times (0)'

loop2: `i=1` -> 'Jimmy Five Times (1)'

loop3: `i=2` -> 'Jimmy Five Times (2)'

loop4: `i=3` -> 'Jimmy Five Times (3)'

Comment: When it changes from an integer into a string, when was it an integer? It's all under ' ', doesn't that make (' + str(i) + ')') a string? Or is it because i is treated as the integer 0? That turns it from the integer zero into the string zero, then it begins to loop 5 times?

Comment: @Dara exactly the integer is the `i` variable so if we want to add it to the other strings we will need to convert it first to string using the `str`

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(10):
    print("This will show up ten times")
```

is similar to

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print("This will show up ten times")
    i = i + 1  # or i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops combine the iterator protocol, infinite loops, and assignment.

```
for i in range(10):
    print("This will show up ten times")
```

is equivalent to

```
itr = iter(range(10))  # Iterator
while True:  # Infinite loop
    try:
        i = next(itr)  # Assignment
    except StopIteration:
        break

    # Body of the for loop starts here.
    print("This will show up ten times")
```

(Python could do away with the `for` loop altogether, but which of the two above would you rather read and write?)

---

Whether the body of the `for` loop uses the variable the loop assigns to is irrelevant; when you *know* the variable is unused (i.e., you only care about the number of iterations, not the value provided for each iteration), you often use `_` as the index.

```
for _ in range(10):
    print("This will show up ten times")
```